# Сумма по полю предварительно отсортировав таблицу SQLite

Tags: sqlite, pyqt, sqlite3, pyqt6

Есть таблица

```
    query.exec("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expenses (ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
                                                         Date VARCHAR(20),
                                                         Category VARCHAR(20), 
                                                         Description VARCHAR(20),
                                                         Balance REAL,
                                                         Status VARCHAR(20))""")
```

Нужно просуммировать поле Balance предварительно отсортировав поле Status по значению Income.
Мой запрос:

```
query.exec("SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM expenses WHERE Status LIKE Income")
```

Но пока не получается

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ

```
query.exec("SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM expenses WHERE Status='Income'")
```